# ui-router: old controller is called on change state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

There's a pagination in my app, and it uses an url part to store the page number: url's look like this: `/someList/1`, `/someList2/` etc.

I'm changing this part using `$state.go($state.current.name, {page: $scope.currentPage}, {reload: false, notify: false});`

And it works fine at this point.

But after any state change the controller of someList is being called. If I change `notify` to true this never happens, but cpoils my pagination logic.

So: is there any way to stop that old controller from being called, maybe in `$stateChangeStart` handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found a workaround:

- set a variable `$rootScope.stateChanging` to `true` in `$stateChangeStart` event handler and to `false` in `$stateChangeSuccess`.
- now it can be used in controllers like `$rootScope.stateChanging || init();` to stop the controller functions from being executed.

I don't think that it's a proper solution, so I've reported this as an issue (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2457), but it may help someone.